# Git Modified Content, Untracked Content Issue

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repository which is empty. Then I added my project folder to that clone repository which contains all the code.

When I say git status it says the following:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   MyCodeFolder (modified content, untracked content)
```

At this time I issue the following git command:

```
git add MyCodeFolder
```

When I do git status I see the same message again.

How can I add "MyCodeFolder" to the repo folder? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that MyCodeFolder has been added as a submodule to the git repository. Did you do that by purpose?

Comment: Nope! I simply dragged the MyCodeFolder into the empty repo folder. How can I fix that?

Comment: If you want to track the folder in the parent repository only, simply remove the `.git` directory in `MyCodeFolder`